# Sorting whole matrix into only one column

Tags: matlab, sorting, matrix

I get a small project to do on scoring system. I found out that if i'm using excel to manipulated it, it definitely cause me a lot of time. I hope i get help from you guys.

```
A = [10 20 30 40 ...]       % (1xm array)
B = [0.02; 0.04;...]        % (nx1 array)
F = A/B                     % F should be (n x m matrix)
Z = zero (size(nxm), 3)     % I'm trying to create a matrix with n x m row and 3 column)
```

I would like to sort F into Z(1:end), Z(1:end) respective A will be in Z(2:end) and respective B will be in Z(3:end). May i know how should i write in Matlab?

Example:

```
       10      20    30    40    50 ...
0.02  500     1000  1500  2000   2500
0.04  250     500   750   1000   1250
0.06 166.67 333.33  500  666.67  833.33 
...
```

output Z

```
166.67  10  0.06
250     10  0.04
333.33  20  0.06
....
```

Hope anyone here can help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you are looking for is either `meshgrid`, or `bsxfun`.
The meshgrid solution:

```
A=[10 20 30 40];
B=[0.02 0.04 0.06 0.08];
[x,y]=meshgrid(A,B); % Generate 2 matrices having the elements to divide
F=x./y;              % Do elemnt-by-element divide
Z=[F(:),x(:),y(:)];  % put all values from the matrices together as columns,
                     % using linear indexing (:).
```

The bsxfun solution is more compact, faster, but less readable:

```
F=bsxfun(@rdivide,A',B); % Put the transpose at B if you want it 
                       % sorted along B.
x=bsxfun(@times,A,ones(size(B,2),1));  % a matric containing A as columns
y=bsxfun(@times,ones(1,size(A,2)),B'); % a matrix containing B repeated as rows
Z=[F(:),x(:),y(:)];
```

The trick with bsxfun is that it does singleton expansion. The inputs get repeated along each dimension having length 1, as much as needed to match the second operand.

So in the 4x4 case above you have (pseudo code):

```
[10 20 30 40] .* [0.01;
                  0.02;
                  0.04;
                  0.06]
```

will be expanded to (also pseudo code):

```
[10 20 30 40;    [0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01;
 10 20 30 40; .*  0.02 0.02 0.02 0.02;
 10 20 30 40;     0.04 0.04 0.04 0.04;
 10 20 30 40]     0.06 0.06 0.06 0.06]
```

It seems you want to have it sorted by F: you can easily accomplish this by using

```
Z_sort = sortrows(Z,[1]);
```

Comment: At least in MATLAB R2012a `F=bsxfun(@divide,A',B);` gives error: `Error using bsxfun Undefined function 'divide' for input arguments of type 'double'.` Changing it to `F=bsxfun(@rdivide,A,B')` solves the problem.

Comment: @jpjacobs, thanks for your input. Just edited the question with F=A/B instead of F=B/A. I change the F=x.\y, there is error. However, F=x./y (A and B must same size). How about A and B are not in the same size?

Comment: It works perfectly for different dimensions. You should have only changed the dimensions in the `ones` commands. Now I made it a bit easier (and using better coding style ;)) for the second version: I put in the correct dimensions inferred from the arrays used instead of hard-coding them. For dividing B by A it suffices to just switch A and B.

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution using `reshape` and linear addressing:

The input data (`A` is a row vector, `B` is a column vector):

```
A = [ 10, 20, 30, 40 ];
B = [ 0.02; 0.04; 0.06; 0.08 ];
```

Here's the code:

```
F = bsxfun(@rdivide, A, B);
Fvector = reshape(F, 1, numel(F));

[SortedFvector, IX] = sort(Fvector);
Aindices = ceil(IX/size(B, 1));

Bindices = mod(IX, size(B, 1));
Bindices(Bindices == 0) = size(B, 1);

Z = [ SortedFvector', A(Aindices)', B(Bindices) ];
```

Comment: Thanks. just edited function F=B/A to A/B. However, just copy and paste your code and run it, the output a bit weird. after that i change rdivide to ldivide, SortedFvector give me the reading of 0.002 (0.02/10). If i wanna the SortedFvector give me the reading of 500 (10/0.02), may i know how should i proceed?

Comment: Note that my solution works with linear addressing, so all these addesses are linear (onedimensional). To get the linear addresses of `500`, get first the linear indices this way: `IX = find(Fvector == 500)` and then convert them to `Aindices` and `Bindices` just as in the code. However, `500` appears on all diagonal elements and this way you'll get them all. After getting `Andices` and `Bindices` using the same commands as the code, you can `Avalue = A(Aindices(1))` (you should get `10`) and `Bvalue = B(Bindices(1))` (you should get `0.02`).

Comment: I'm still unable to get the correct F. I only able to get the answer of F in 0.02/10 instead of 10/0.02...